# Can perspective property be animated (transitioned) from initial (0 / none) to a given value?

Tags: jquery, css, transition, perspective

I'm trying to animate perspective from whatever the initial value is to 1000px over 2 seconds. If I set initial perspective to 0 or 'initial', the transition-duration property does not work at all. It works when initial value is set to some ridiculous number like, 100000px but it's not clean. Any ideas?

Css:

```
main {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    //border: 5px solid red;
     //perspective: 1000px;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    perspective: 0px;
}

.perspective {
  perspective: 1000px;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#cube').hover(
    function() {
        $('main').addClass('perspective');
    }, function() {
        $('main').removeClass('perspective');
    }
);
```

Comment: You could set the initial value to `0px`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work at all